# Using manim to make a graph like network with slightly moving nodes

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, manim

[image]

trying to recreate that by using [valuetrackers](https://pastebin.com/MzNj5dQF)

Here is my code and the err is also inside that pastebin
Thank you for all the help since I cannot yet create an animation I thought about using this to make by
 linking the dots and lines both to some lists of valuetrackers and then finally storing the updation of these value trackers in an animation list and finally playing them was my goal

```
class Network3(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        screen_grid = ScreenGrid()
        self.add(screen_grid)
        #function to just random the x and y coordinates
        def randomize_xy():
            for i in range(0,no_of_dots):
                x_coord[i]=random.randint(-7,+7)
                y_coord[i]=random.randint(-4,+4)

            print(x_coord)
            print(y_coord)
        no_of_dots=20

        #make some dots
        dots=[]
        for i in range(0,no_of_dots):
            dots.append(Dot())

        #make initial list of coordinates 
        x_coord=[]
        y_coord=[]
        for i in range(0,no_of_dots):
            x_coord.append(random.randint(-7,7))
            y_coord.append(random.randint(-4,4))      

        # #make sure all the lengths are ok
        # print(f"length of dots lenght={len(dots)} of x_coord={len(x_coord)}") error of int base 10 is coming from here
        print("length of dots=",end="")
        print(str(len(dots))) #print(len(dots)) still causes an error !!!

        #add all dots at one point
        self.add(*dots)

        #make anim list to move everything to their position from origin
        animlist=[]
        for i in range(0,no_of_dots):
            animlist.extend([dots[i].move_to,[x_coord[i],y_coord[i],0]])

        #play
        self.play(*animlist)

        #make a list of value trackers
        x_trackers=[]
        y_trackers=[]

        for i in range(0,no_of_dots):
            x_tracker=ValueTracker(x_coord[i])
            y_tracker=ValueTracker(y_coord[i])

            x_trackers.append(x_tracker)
            y_trackers.append(y_tracker)

        #making lines
        lines=[]
        for i in range(0,no_of_dots-1):
            t1=[x_coord[i],y_coord[i],0]
            t2=[x_coord[i+1],y_coord[i+1],0]
            line=Line(t1,t2)
            lines.append(line)

        def update_func1(obj,i):
            temp1=np.array([x_trackers[i],y_trackers[i],0])
            temp2=np.array([x_trackers[i+1],y_trackers[i+1],0])
            line=Line(start=temp1,end=temp2)
            obj.become(line)

        #making a link between each line and value tracker 
        for i in range(0,no_of_dots-1):
            lines[i].add_updater(lambda m:update_func1(m,i))

        #adding again
        self.add(*lines)

        #making a link between each dot and value tracker 
        for i in range(0,no_of_dots):
            dots[i].add_updater(lambda m:m.move_to([x_trackers[i],y_trackers[i],0]))

        #now somehow have to change all the value tracker at once
        animlist2=[]
        for i in range(0,no_of_dots):
            animlist2.extend([x_trackers[i].set_value,random.randint(-7,+7)])
            animlist2.extend([y_trackers[i].set_value,random.randint(-4,+4)])

        #now play 
        self.play(*animlist2)

        #end
        self.wait(3)
```

Current error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\manim\manimlib\extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "C:\manim\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "network_graphic.py", line 584, in construct
    lines[i].add_updater(lambda m:update_func1(m,i))
  File "C:\manim\manimlib\mobject\mobject.py", line 192, in add_updater
    self.update(0)
  File "C:\manim\manimlib\mobject\mobject.py", line 159, in update
    updater(self)
  File "network_graphic.py", line 584, in <lambda>
    lines[i].add_updater(lambda m:update_func1(m,i))
  File "network_graphic.py", line 578, in update_func1
    line=Line(start=temp1,end=temp2)
  File "C:\manim\manimlib\mobject\geometry.py", line 431, in __init__
    self.set_start_and_end_attrs(start, end)
  File "C:\manim\manimlib\mobject\geometry.py", line 471, in set_start_and_end_attrs
    vect = normalize(rough_end - rough_start)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ValueTracker' and 'ValueTracker'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use the functions with "dt", then watch my video if you have any doubts. This is a basic example Grant made in one of his very old videos, but I think you can use it for your idea.

```py
class RandomMove(Scene):
    CONFIG = {
        "amplitude": 0.4,
        "jiggles_per_second": 1,
    }
    def construct(self):
        points = VGroup(*[
            Dot(radius=0.2) for _ in range(9)
        ])
        points.arrange_in_grid(buff=1)
        for submob in points:
            submob.jiggling_direction = rotate_vector(
                RIGHT, np.random.random() * TAU *1.5,
            )
            submob.jiggling_phase = np.random.random() * TAU *1.5

        def update_mob(mob, dt):
            for submob in mob:
                submob.jiggling_phase += dt * self.jiggles_per_second * TAU
                submob.shift(
                    self.amplitude *
                    submob.jiggling_direction *
                    np.sin(submob.jiggling_phase) * dt
                )

        points.add_updater(update_mob)
        self.add(points)
        self.wait(10)
```

Result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8djmg.jpg)

Comment: @ Theoremof Beethoven ,I tried to run your code on manimce and i am getting the error message  .....AttributeError: 'RandomMove' object has no attribute 'jiggles_per_second'

Comment: @sajjadveeri You have to convert it to ManimCE, to see the most important differences watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrZDKC9Buxk).

Comment: ,your manim tutorials are really  a great help to anyone serious about learning manim.The documentation of ManimCE is really very scarce and surface type.I think it would be all the great if you start  a series of lectures on ManimCe,especially about methods and functions for which there are no examples provided. or write a book or something about it.Manim community all over the world would be very grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet at least imo is to use a `MoveAlongPath()` animation, and then apply it for each node of a `Graph()` object `g` for instance with different paths at which each node follows. What the path each node will follow depends on what you want for instance I wrote the code below that moves a "node" or in my sample a dot along a trefoil knot parametric function (which you can think of as a graph that looks like a trinity knot):

```
class TrefoilarMovingDot(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        trefoil_knot = ParametricFunction(lambda t: np.array([
            np.sin(t) + 2 * np.sin(2 * t),
            np.cos(t) - 2 * np.cos(2 * t),
            0
        ]), [-3.5, 3.5])
        trefoil_knot.scale(0.25)

        dot = Dotdot = Dot(color=ORANGE, stroke_width=5, fill_opacity=0.5)
        dot.scale(1)

        # uncomment this if you want the knot to be invisible and still
        # have movement of the dot in trefoilar motion
        self.add(trefoil_knot)
        self.play(MoveAlongPath(dot, trefoil_knot), rate_func=linear, run_time=5)
```

We can even use a more generalized parametric equation for knots to make the dot or node move in different paths. here is an example of a dot moving in a "quadrifoliar" path:

```
class QuadrifoliarMovingDot(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        # note that increasing k to 3 will make it a trefoilar knot
        # to 4 will make it a knot with 8 "rays" to 5 will make it
        # a cinquefoil knot to 6 will make it a knot with 12 "rays"
        # and so on. So this parametric function can be generalized
        # not only to a trefoil, quadrifolium, and cinquefoil knots
        k = 2
        knot = ParametricFunction(lambda t: np.array([
            np.cos(k * t) * np.cos(t),
            np.cos(k * t) * np.sin(t),
            0
        ]), [-3.5, 3.5])
        knot.scale(.5)

        dot = Dotdot = Dot(color=ORANGE, stroke_width=5, fill_opacity=0.5)
        dot.scale(1)

        # uncomment this if you want the knot to be invisible and still
        # have movement of the dot in trefoilar motion
        self.add(knot)
        self.play(MoveAlongPath(dot, knot), rate_func=linear, run_time=5)
```